# How to get an specific header value from the HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpclient, httpresponse, baasbox

I'm making an HTTP call. My response contains a session code `X-BB-SESSION` in the header section of the `HttpResponseMessage` object. How do I get that specific header value?

I am using a foreach statement to iterate through all the headers ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.headers.httpresponseheadercollection.aspx)). However the compiler keeps saying that it cannot be done:

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
  System.net.http.headers.cachecontrolheadervalue because
  'System.net.http.headers.cachecontrolheadervalue' doesn't contain
  a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

This is the code I'm trying:

```
//Connection code to BaasBox

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //get the headers
    HttpResponseHeaders responseHeadersCollection = response.Headers;
    foreach (var value in responseHeadersCollection.CacheControl)  --> HERE
    {
        string sTemp = String.Format("CacheControl {0}={1}", value.Name, value.Value);
    } 
}
else {
   Console.WriteLine("X-BB-SESSION: NOT Found");
}
```

The header content from where I'm trying to get the value (`X-BB-SESSION` value) is something like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *    
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With    
X-BB-SESSION: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Don't you mean windows phone 8.1?

Comment: Could be both WP 8 or WP 8.1 When I started doing the test, it was in WP8. Now with the automatic update I have WP 8.1 However, the same code is working until this point (to get an especific header)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`TryGetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.trygetvalues.aspx) method.

```
HttpHeaders headers = response.Headers;
IEnumerable<string> values;
if (headers.TryGetValues("X-BB-SESSION", out values))
{
  string session = values.First();
}
```

Comment: Note: First() is an extension method; include System.Linq to get access to it.

Comment: Rather than `IEnumberable<string>`, I needed to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues`

Comment: so what happens if the "X-BB-SESSION" doesn't exist?

Comment: @Shilan In that case, "TryGetValues" will return false and the "if" will not be entered.

Answer (score 29):

Using Linq aswell, this is how I solved it.

```
string operationLocation = response.Headers.GetValues("Operation-Location").FirstOrDefault();
```

I think it's clean and not too long.

Comment: Note that this will throw an exception if the header is not found. If that's what you want, you may as well use First() instead of FirstOrDefault().

Comment: FirstOrDefault(); will throw exception if "Operation-Location" is not available -

Answer (score 26):

Though Sam's answer is correct. It can be somewhat simplified, and avoid the unneeded variable.

```
IEnumerable<string> values;
string session = string.Empty;
if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("X-BB-SESSION", out values))
{
    session = values.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Or, using a single statement with a ternary operator (as commented by @SergeySlepov):

```
string session = response.Headers.TryGetValues("X-BB-SESSION", out var values) ? values.FirstOrDefault() : null;
```

Comment: If you go that route, then you can remove 1 more variable:  `response.Headers.TryGetValues("X-BB-SESSION", out var values)`

Comment: @GuillaumePerrot you are correct. But this was added in c# 7, so I used the "old" way for compatibility.

Comment: To go all the way, use: `string session = response.Headers.TryGetValues("X-BB-SESSION", out var values) ? values.FirstOrDefault() : null;`

Comment: worked flawlessly for me

Answer (score 7):

If someone like method-based queries then you can try:

```
    var responseValue = response.Headers.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Key=="X-BB-SESSION").Value.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to enumerate one header (CacheControl) instead of all the headers, which is strange. To see all the headers, use

```
foreach (var value in responseHeadersCollection)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("CacheControl {0}={1}", value.Name, value.Value);
}
```

to get one specific header, convert the Headers to a dictionary and then get then one you want

```
Debug.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToDictionary(l=>l.Key,k=>k.Value)["X-BB-SESSION"]);
```

This will throw an exception if the header is not in the dictionary so you better check it using ContainsKey first

Comment: Hi Igor. I tested your code as well and it works. I justbfigured out another alternative to get the same value. thanks!

Comment: Perhaps something like Debug.WriteLine(response.Headers.FirstOrDefault(k=>k.Key == "X-BB-SESSION")?.Value.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: "...convert the Headers to a Dictionary..." see https://dotnetcodr.com/2014/03/13/extension-methods-in-net-part-3-mixture-of-useful-methods/

Answer (score 0):

Below Code Block Gives A formatted view of Response Headers

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://-------.com");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

```
        foreach (var headerItem in response.Headers)
        {

            IEnumerable<string> values;
            string HeaderItemValue="";
            values = response.Headers.GetValues(headerItem.ToString());

            foreach (var valueItem in values)
            {
                HeaderItemValue = HeaderItemValue + valueItem + ";";                    
            }

            Console.WriteLine(headerItem + " : " + HeaderItemValue);
        }
```