# Reading a specific header from HttpClient response (POST)

Tags: xamarin

I'm using HttpClient PostAsync to a server that will provide an authentication token in the response header.  The header name is "Authorization".  How can I get this value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an specific header value from the HttpResponseMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439421/how-to-get-an-specific-header-value-from-the-httpresponsemessage)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<string> authHeaders = (System.Collections.Generic.List<string>)response.Headers.GetValues("Authorization");
authHeaders[0];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.