parsing web post response for access key
I've made what appears to be a successful POST httpwebrequest.
I'm getting 15 (result.Headers.Count - 1) headers back with data.
result.Headers(13)  reveals
"fpc=Arg8nm0VqblMnu3rWck9GCw; expires=Wed, 05-Jun-2024 15:59:45 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None,esctx=PAQABBwEAAADnfolhJpSnRYB1SVj-Hgd8jINyVhrdWcuTdgm378vqo8Qo9ZgPGeuBNHyLhH1nZC8AfCBrfkJjbWVgfmt1yGtOCMmbLDUwDm4pPKp2qiUmCJHs5cnVcv--Oc4Q9LsQLS9m0znPAPGdAojpzBNGZ6tQPQTnroP24HSg4I53tNhF4j-u2orVUJBod72dh620NqggAA; domain=.login.microsoftonline.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None,x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd; path=/; secure; httponly,stsservicecookie=estsfd; path=/; secure; httponly"
Within that  result.Headers(13)  I see  esctx=PAQABBwEAAADnfolhJpSnRYB1SVj-Hgd8jINyVhrdWcuTdgm378vqo8Qo9ZgPGeuBNHyLhH1nZC8AfCBrfkJjbWVgfmt1yGtOCMmbLDUwDm4pPKp2qiUmCJHs5cnVcv--Oc4Q9LsQLS9m0znPAPGdAojpzBNGZ6tQPQTnroP24HSg4I53tNhF4j-u2orVUJBod72dh620NqggAA;
Is that the oAuth response access key I need ??
If so How do I parse it out.   Actual POST Request code Code is below.
Thanks
  Private Sub RunRequest()
  Dim s As HttpWebRequest
  Dim enc As UTF8Encoding
  Dim postdata As String
  Dim postdatabytes As Byte()
  Dim url As String = ("https://login.microsoftonline.com/ca4f5969-c10f-40d4-8127-e74b691f95de/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration")
  'Dim url As String = ("https://login.microsoftonline.com/ca4f5969-c10f-40d4-8127-e74b691f95de/oauth2/v2.0/token")
  s = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
  enc = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
  postdata = "client_id=4e502cbc-a55f-4341-a498-69cfbe19ee7b&client_secret=0Ag8Q~QgsWJ55mz9SWG6hf22b_7mZ2m~.nInpagc&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https://tffproduction.onmicrosoft.com/04cc9749-dbe5-4914-b262-d866b907756b/.default"
  postdatabytes = enc.GetBytes(postdata)
  s.Method = "POST"
  s.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  s.ContentLength = postdatabytes.Length

  Using stream = s.GetRequestStream()
      stream.Write(postdatabytes, 0, postdatabytes.Length)
  End Using

  Dim result As WebResponse

  Try
      result = s.GetResponse()
      Dim breakpoint As String = Nothing
  Catch ex As Exception
      Dim errmsg As String = ex.Message
  End Try
  Dim sb As New StringBuilder
  Dim hdkey As String

  For I As Int32 = 0 To result.Headers.Count - 1
      hdkey = result.Headers(I)
      sb.Append(result.Headers(I))
      sb.AppendLine()

  Next
  Dim Hdrs As String = sb.ToString

End Sub

If you are trying to get a specific header value, this might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439421/how-to-get-an-specific-header-value-from-the-httpresponsemessage#:~:text=You%20should%20be%20able%20to%20use%20the%20TryGetValues,%28headers.TryGetValues%28%22X-BB-SESSION%22%2C%20out%20values%29%29%20%7B%20string%20session%20%3D%20values.First%28%29%3B

Thanks JamesF.   I got is working using a split function.  Appreciate your response
